# После выполнения ajax запроса и закрытия модального окна оно не открывает заново. В чем проблема?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

```js
/* Обновление игры через AJAX */
    $('.saveBtnInModal').click(function (e) {
        var formData = new FormData($("#editFormModal")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'games/updateGameInfo',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                // до отправки данных, можно поставить например гифку loading
                swal.showLoading();
            },

            success: function (data) {
                // удача
                swal({
                    title: 'Данные игры успешно обновлены!',
                    type: 'success',
                    timer: 3000
                }).then(
                    function () {
                    },
                    // handling the promise rejection
                    function (dismiss) {
                        if (dismiss === 'timer') {
                        }
                    }
                );
                $("#gamesTable").load(location.href + ' #gamesTable');
                $('.modal').modal('hide')
            },

            error: function (data) {
                // если ошибка, показываем ошибку
                swal({
                    title: 'Ошибка! Что-то не так!',
                    type: 'error',
                    timer: 10000
                }).then(
                    function () {
                    },
                    // handling the promise rejection
                    function (dismiss) {
                        if (dismiss === 'timer') {
                        }
                    }
                );
            },

            complete: function () {
                // после завершения запроса, с любым исходом. Убираем гифку загрузки

            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".editBtnModal").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            var id_games = $(this).data('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "games/getGameInfo",
                data: {id_games: id_games},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // до отправки данных, можно поставить например гифку loading
                    swal.enableLoading();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // удача
                    var editFormModal = $('#editFormModal');
                    editFormModal.find('#id_games').val(data.id_games);
                    editFormModal.find('#game_name').val(data.game_name);
                    editFormModal.find('#game_desc').val(data.game_desc);
                    editFormModal.find('#steam_link').val(data.steam_link);
                    editFormModal.find('#id_developer').val(data.id_developer);
                    swal.close();
                    $('.modal').modal('show')

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    // если ошибка, показываем ошибку
                    swal({
                        title: 'Ошибка! Что-то не так!',
                        type: 'error',
                        timer: 10000
                    }).then(
                        function () {
                        },
                        // handling the promise rejection
                        function (dismiss) {
                            if (dismiss === 'timer') {
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                complete: function () {
                    // после завершения запроса, с любым исходом. Убираем гифку загрузки
                },
            });
            $('#exampleModalLabel').text('Редактировать');
            $('#editFormModal').show();
            $('#formAddNewGame').hide();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Кнопка

```
<button type="button" data-value="34" class="btn btn-primary 
  editBtnModal">Редактировать</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделал конструкцию

```
$('body').on('click', '.editBtnModal',function (e) {

});
```

и всё работает